# Error when searching one of the columns in DataTable (serverSide: true)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, datatable

[image]

> DataTables warning: table id=datauser - Exception Message:
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.nama' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `users` left join `tb_operator` on `tb_operator`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `tb_mahasiswa` on `tb_mahasiswa`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where (LOWER(`users`.`username`) LIKE %k% or LOWER(`users`.`nama`) LIKE %k% or LOWER(`users`.`role`) LIKE %k% or LOWER(`users`.`updated_at`) LIKE %k%) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null) count_row_table)

I got the field 'nama' by IFNULL two table columns into one (AS nama), but weirdly DataTable search searching nama in the table users... the ordering and paginating working fine though.
How do I fix DataTable search so it can look up 'nama' instead of 'users.nama'?

Controller:

```
$table = User::select(\DB::RAW('users.id, users.username, IFNULL(tb_operator.nama_operator,tb_mahasiswa.nama_mahasiswa) AS nama, users.role, users.updated_at'))
                ->join('tb_operator', 'tb_operator.user_id', '=', 'users.id', 'left')
                ->join('tb_mahasiswa', 'tb_mahasiswa.user_id', '=', 'users.id', 'left');
```

DataTable:

```
var datauser = $('#datauser').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{{ action('UserC@data') }}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false, searchable: false },
            { data: 'username', name: 'users.username' },
            { 
                data: 'nama',
                render: function (data) {
                    return data;
                }
            },
            { 
                data: 'role',
                name: 'users.role',
                render: function (data) {
                    badge = 'danger';
                    if (data == 'mahasiswa') {
                        badge = 'info';
                    } else if(data == 'publik') {
                        badge = 'warning';
                    } else if(data == 'operator') {
                        badge = 'success';
                    }
                    return '<span class="badge badge-' + badge + '">' + data + '</span>';
                } 
            },
            { data: 'last_update', name: 'users.updated_at'},
            { 
                data: 'action',
                name: 'action',
                searchable: false, 
                orderable: false,
                render: function (action) {
                    return '<div class="text-center">' + action + '</div>';
                } 
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: you need to use https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables to handel datatable in serve

Comment: @KamleshPaul but I already installed it though (~8.0), the other columns work when searched (intentionally avoiding word that only available on field nama)